# How to get a List<E> from a HashMap<String,List<E>>

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I want to extract a `List<E>` from a `Map<String, List<E>>` (`E` is a random Class) using `stream()`.

I want a simple one-line method using java 8's stream.

What I have tried until now :

```
HashMap<String,List<E>> map = new HashMap<>();
List<E> list = map.values(); // does not compile
list = map.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList()); // does not compile
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`map.values()` returns a `Collection<List<E>>` not a `List<E>`, if you want the latter then you're required to flatten the nested `List<E>` into a single `List<E>` as follows:

```
List<E> result = map.values()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(List::stream)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 15):

Or use `forEach`

```
 map.forEach((k,v)->list.addAll(v));
```

or as Aomine commented use this

```
map.values().forEach(list::addAll);
```

Comment: @Aomine `values()` may involve a construction of an expensive intermediate object, thus simply ignoring `k` may be advantageous from a performance perspective.

Comment: @oakad You're correct in the sense that `values` may involve creating a new object but note that the returned collection by `values`  is lazily created **once**, thereafter, the same instance will be returned. So it's not so expensive after all. Further, I'd favour readability here which means `map.values().forEach(list::addAll)`.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an alternate way to do it with Java-9 and above:

```
List<E> result = map.values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.flatMapping(List::stream, Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: Just the apiNote :- *The `flatMapping()` collectors are most useful when used in a multi-level reduction*, such as downstream of a `groupingBy` or `partitioningBy`.

Comment: It decreases indeed the readability here. The Java 8 way is clearly more relevant here.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers:

```
List<E> result = map.values()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

This could also do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use :-

```
map.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collection.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#stream()) with `flatMap` as:

```
Map<String, List<E>> map = new HashMap<>(); // program to interface
List<E> list = map.values()
                  .stream()
                  .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

or use a non-stream version as:

```
List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
map.values().forEach(list::addAll)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Collectors2.flatCollect`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/9.2.0/org/eclipse/collections/impl/collector/Collectors2.html#flatCollect-org.eclipse.collections.api.block.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-) from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections)

```
List<String> list = 
    map.values().stream().collect(Collectors2.flatCollect(l -> l, ArrayList::new));
```

You can also adapt the `Map` and use the Eclipse Collections `MutableMap` API.

```
List<String> list = 
    Maps.adapt(map).asLazy().flatCollect(l -> l).toList();
```

The method `flatCollect` is equivalent to the method `flatMap`, except `flatCollect` takes an `Iterable` instead of a `Stream`.

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.