# How to extract a List<D> from a HashMap<E,R> using stream

Tags: java, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I want to know how to extract a `List<D>` from a `HashMap<E,R>` considering these constraints:

- `E` is a custom class;
- `R` is a custom class containing a `Set<D>` of custom objects;

What I have tried: I tried addressing the issue in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054448/how-to-get-a-liste-from-a-hashmapstring-liste).

In that previous case, I had a simple `Map<E,List<R>>`, but in this case I have to access the `R` class which has the targeted `Set<D>`.

What I want to do in the following portion of the code is to get the Elements of the `Set<D>` whose country names are equal to the given parameter.

I have tried using the same solution :

```
Map<E,R> map = new HashMap<E,R>();
public List<D> method(String countryname) { 
   return map.values().stream().filter((x)->{
        return x.getSet().stream().anyMatch((t) -> {
            return t.getCountry().equals(countryname); 
        });
    })
    .map(R::getSet)
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); //does not compile
}

// the R class
class R {
    private Set<D> set = new TreeSet<D>();
    //getters & setters & other attributes
}
```

Comment: @nullpointer Just in case you didn't know, the OP already gets a notification when you post an answer to their question. There's no need to post a comment with a link to the answer.

Comment: As Holger pointed out in a comment as well, using [the solution that I'd suggested to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54054505/1746118) could have avoided this failure. i.e. using `Collection::stream`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the `flatMap` step is wrong, since your `map` step transforms your `Stream<R>` to a `Stream<Set<D>>`, so `flatMap(List::stream)` should be `flatMap(Set::stream)`:

```
return map.values()
          .stream()
          .filter(x -> x.getSet().stream().anyMatch(t -> t.getCountry().equals(countryname)))
          .map(R::getSet)
          .flatMap(Set::stream)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Besides, as you can notice above, the code can be much more readable if you avoid using curly braces when you don't have to.

Comment: A problem that could be avoided by simply using `Collection::stream` or replacing the two steps `.map(R::getSet) .flatMap(Set::stream)` with a single `.flatMap(r -> r.getSet().stream())`…

Comment: @nullpointer assuming that `getSet()` always returns the same or an equivalent set, the OP’s code and this solution will include *all* elements of all sets containing at least one matching element, whereas your solution will contain only the matching elements.

Answer (score 4):

In order to improve readability of your code I would suggest avoiding unnecessary curly braces in lambdas and even the lambdas themselves. Use *method references* where possible.

```
return map.values()
          .stream()
          .map(R::getSet)
          .filter(set -> set.stream()
                            .map(R::getCountry)
                            .anyMatch(countryname::equals))
          .flatMap(Set::stream)
          .collect(toList());
```

The last `flatMap` and `collect` operations can be shortened to one line:

```
.collect(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, List::addAll);
```

Or if you're using Java 9:

```
.collect(flatMapping(Set::stream, toList()));
```

However it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

> get the Elements of the Set whose country names are equal to the given
>   parameter.

You seem to be looking for

```
// input as parameter to the method for simplicity
public List<D> method(Map<E, R> map, String countryName) {
    return map.values() // Collection<R>
              .stream() // Stream<R>
              .flatMap(a -> a.getSet().stream()) // Stream<D>
              .filter(t -> t.getCountry().equals(countryName)) // filtered
              .collect(Collectors.toList()); // collected to list
}
```

Comment: The two solutions posted in the two answers are not equivalent. I corrected the error in the OPs attempt, without changing their logic, since I assumed that's what the they wanted. Only the OP can say which of the two options is what they wanted.

Comment: @Eran Indeed, that's what I was wondering the `anyMatch` in your solution was. Leaving it to the OP then. Thanks again. :)